# How to fix Nikon SB 60 flash that is too tight in Stitz hotshoe?

Tags: nikon, repair, hotshoe-flash, adapter

My Nikon SB60 flash is too tight in the vintage Stitz hotshoe. It is almost impossible to remove despite the locking pin being held clear using the flash locking lever.

I would like to use a coldshoe adapter to coldshoe adapter but there are so many on offer that I just do not understand the permutations. It needs to fit smoothly (in and out) of the vintage Stitz hotshoe and accept the Nikon SB60 without jamming on the data pins. I will use the remote triggering for the flash.

Recommendations for the adaptor, please.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off "tuning" the Stitz.

I looked for pictures of these, and the ones I found are the classic U-bent metal construction.

You may be able to find something that is a little thicker than the space in the "U" — a small screwdriver, perhaps — and force it in there, to spread the "U" a small amount. This would make your Nikon fit in better.

I've used this technique successfully on "vintage" hot shoes. Spread a little bit at a time, trying the fit of your Nikon each time. If you go a bit too far, making the Nikon flash "wobbly," you can tap the top of the "U" with a small hammer to make it tighter.

If this all seems a bit scary, or if you are not very confident with such tools, then the next thing I'd do is try to find a used photo gear store, or attend a swap meet. Then, you can actually try the various adapters before buying.

I'm guessing such a thing might cost a dollar or two at a swap-meet, but perhaps $10-$20 if bought new.

Comment: Thank you, it is the nikon pins fouling on the flat bottom rails, the flashgun goes in but is very difficult to remove.

Comment: Jan Steinman, your answer made me think, and I remembered I had three Stitz Bounce head hot shoes. I located them and removed the stop pins. I tried all three and one of them accepted the Nikon SB60 shoe with no problem and is a good firm fit, easy to remove as well! Thank you for the memory jog.

Comment: Glad I could help!